# Is is possible to post a Facebook Open Graph Story using the Feed Dialog and a Direct URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Using Facebook's Feed Dialog [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) I'm able to post a story using a URL exactly like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=458358780877780&
link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

My story is posting, but it's *missing* the Open Graph "action" and "object" types.

Is it possible to publish an Open Graph story with the associated "action" and "object" types via the Feed Dialog-Direct URL method? Am I missing a parameter in the URL? What is the proper form?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to post Open Graph story through Feed Dialog?

Comment: The Feed Dialog approach does not require a FB app install and has very little friction, so you should get more stories posted. I've read that 50% or more of users will drop-off at the app install dialog.

Comment: Indeed, you are true. I never thought it that way. Will you be using Custom Objects and Action or generic Open Graph Objects?

Comment: Custom Actions and Objects.

Answer (score 0):

The FEED dialog is deprecated in V.2, you should use 'share'.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Try using share dialog. Please post your doubts in your comment.

Comment: You say its deprecated but in the docs it says to use the FeedDialog as fallback?

Comment: sorry for that but I just read the notice on the head in the docs... :)

But I still prefer to use share-dialog if I was you...

Comment: I would prefer to use the ShareDialog but in the documentation it says to use the FeedDialog as a backup solution in case they don't have the Facebook App installed on their device. In any case, I am now calling straight to the Graph API as a backup.